# Getting a Summation Expression

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

> **Q.**  A sequence of numbers ${A_n},\,n = 1,\,2,\,3,\,...$  is defined as follows:
>   $$\,\,\,\,\,{A_1} = {1 \over 2}\,\,{\rm{and}}\,{\rm{for}}\,{\rm{each}}\,n \ge 2,\,{A_n} = \left( {{{2n - 3} \over {2n}}} \right){A_{n - 1}},\,{\rm{then}}\,{\rm{prove}}\,{\rm{that}}\,\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {{A_k}}  < 1,\,\,n \ge 1$$

**Sol:**$${A_k} = \left( {{{2k - 3} \over {2k}}} \right){A_{k - 1}},\,\,k \ge 2$$$$2k{A_k} = (2k - 3){A_{k - 1}},\,\,k \ge 2$$$$2k{A_k} - 2(k - 1){A_{k - 1}} =  - {A_{k - 1}},\,\,k \ge 2$$          The next step in the solution was -$$2(n + 1){A_{n + 1}} - 2{A_1} =  - \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {{A_k}} $$
          I think he applies summation on both sides of the equation but I couldn't get the $LHS$.
           Can anyone help me in getting the $LHS$?

Comment: Maybe a case for Raabe's test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a telescoping sum: one has $4A_2-2A_1=-A_1$, $6A_3-4A_2=-A_2$,
etc., up to $2(n+1)A_{n+1}-2nA_n=-A_n$. Adding these up,
$$-\sum_{k=1}^n A_k=(2(n+1)A_{n+1}-2nA_n)+\cdots+(6A_3-4A_2)+(4A_2-2A_1)$$
and on the right almost everything cancels, just leaving $2(n+1)A_{n+1}-2A_1$.